# Sequence/series with triangular(?) pattern emerging

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, number-theory, summation, geometric-series

What i thought was a geometric series of the following form:

$$N = \sum_{i=1}^n[N_{i-1} + (T-N_{i-1})P]$$ where $$ lim_{i \to \infty} N = T$$ and $$N_{i=0}=0$$
I find the series to do the following:
$$i=1 : N = TP$$
$$i=2 : N = 2TP-TP^2$$
$$i=3 : N = 3TP-3TP^2 + TP^3$$
$$i=4 : N = 4TP-6TP^2+4TP^3-TP^4$$
$$i=5 : N = 5TP-10TP^2+10TP^3-5TP^4+TP^5$$
$$etc$$

I have been unable to find a solution to reduce this series, and am wondering in general about the pattern emerging.

added:
I see that this series mimics a converging inverse exponential, approximately:
$$N_n=T(1-e^{-Pn})$$

Comment: Note the occurrence of [binomial coefficients](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient)

Comment: I have edited the summation as it was originally incorrect. 
I have added that i see it as an approximate inverse exponential

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your **sequence** $\{N_i\}$ appears to be defined by $$N_{i+1} = N_{i} + (T-N_{i})P.$$
Therefore $$N_{i+1}-T = (N_{i}-T)(1-P) $$

$$N_k-T = (N_{0}-T)(1-P)^k=-T(1-P)^k.$$

We thus have  $$N_k =T(1-(1-P)^k)$$ which, of course, produces the binomial pattern of the terms you have found.

Comment: Could you please explain the defined→therefore step, i am not particularly good at these things.

Comment: Subtract $T$ from both sides. On the RHS,  you then have $(N_i-T) -P(N_i-T) $ and you can take out the common factor of $(N_i-T)$. Is that OK now?

Comment: i figured it was this simple. very nice, thank you

Comment: You're very welcome.

Comment: can you expand on where the k exponent is added to (1-P); line 3

Comment: Yes, in your mind think of the sequence $N_0-T, N_1-T, N_2-T, ...$. By the previous line each one of these terms is $(1-P)$ times the previous one. Therefore the $k$th one is $(1-P)^k$ times the first.